# Using @Action annotation in openjpa

Tags: annotations, openjpa

In my open jpa class, we have a method like this:

```
@Action(Action.ACTION_TYPE.CREATE)
public void createRecord(EntityObject fileStatus) {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.persist(fileStatus);
    em.flush();

}
```

My question is with the @Action usage. I was of the impression that we use Annotations to avoid writing boilerplate code. In this particular method, what would be the boilerplate code that we would avoid by using the annotation? I think the method would look same even without the Annotation.

Comment: What is the @Action annotation about? That isn't an OpenJPA / JPA annotation.

Comment: public @interface Action in package com.ibm.jpa.web

Answer (score 0):

It's annotation used by IBM Rational Application Developer (RAD) - [Related answer on IBM support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21443632).

Annotations can be used for documenting purposes only - in that case they doesn't affect compiled code.

This one is most likely used by RAD to recognize specific JPA manager methods so it can list them in modeling tools there (this last is only mine guess).